# Whenever my page loads i want the textboxes to be empty.how to achieve this using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fax page with six input fields. all the input fields are textboxes. Whenever the page loads, I want the textboxes to be empty.

I load this page using page init. It is a static page.

How is this possible using JavaScript?

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#faxIdcard',function(event){
    $('#faxpageyes').bind('click',function(event){
        validationVal = validateFax(); 
        if (validationVal == 0)
        {  
            faxObject.faxNumber= $("#fax1").val+$("#fax2").val+$("#fax3").val();
            faxObject.from=$("#fromfaxpage ").val();
            faxObject.fromPhoneNumber=$("#senderfaxpage ").val();
            faxObject.to=$("# tofaxpage").val();
            faxObject.configurationEmailAddress=$("#configfaxpage ").val();
            /**faxObject.faxcoverpage=$("#coverfaxpage ").val();**/
            faxObject.notes=$("#textareafaxpage ").val(); 

            if($('#faxincludepage').is(":checked")){
                faxObject.faxcoverpage = "True";
            }else
            {
                faxObject.faxcoverpage = "False";
            }   

            return true;    
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form *').filter(':input').val('');
```